# Printf: pops out after the break statement

Tags: c

Being at the very beginning of learning programming,
C in particular, I am struggling with how to restrict 
printf only to the valid outputs, i.e. to make sure
that printf does not appear after the "break" statement.

I understand that my test for scanf is within the for
loop, and when i reaches 3 the for loop stops and printf
appears. I hope to find the correct way to both test
scanf, and make sure printf doesn't appear after 
the break statement (in case user types in integers).

```
// a program that calculates the average of an array 
of 3 floating-point values and check if correct inputs
are types in scans (only floating values)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    float values[3];
    float element, average;
    float sum = 0;
    int i, n;
    bool is_float;


    printf ("Please, enter 3 floating values:  \n");

    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%f", &element);

            is_float = 1;
            n = (int) element;

        if (n - element == 0 || element == 0 )
            {
                is_float = 0;
                printf ("Sorry, invalid input\n");
                break;
            }

            else 
            {
                values[i] = element;
                sum += values[i];
            }
    }
    printf ("The average of 3 values is %.2f\n", sum / 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't clear.  What specific behaviour are you seeing, and what were you expecting?

Comment: Maybe you want `return 1;` instead of `break;`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: printf should print the message "The average of 3 values is.." only when valid inputs (&element) are entered; if elements are invalid, i.e. integers (not floating), then the program breaks (stops) and no printf should appear, but for now it appears even after the break statement.

Comment: You could make the execution of the `printf()` dependent on `is_float`. Like `if (is_float) printf(...); ` Otherwise do as suggested by EOF. Why are you using `is_float` at all if not for this purpose?

Comment: Look your code, `break` is used to get out of the for loop. And just out there there is your `printf()`. Based on this why in your opinion the  `printf()` shouldn't be executed?

Comment: Recommend checking the return value of `scanf ("%f", &element) == 1` before using `element`

Comment: @chux: I would be grateful if you explain what checking the return of scanf means. I am at the very beginning, so don't yet have enough knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of successfully scanned fields.  Check online details  for how it handles `%n` and sometimes returns 0 or EOF.

Comment: @chux I've searched to find an explanation, which I would be able to understand, on scanf return values, but to no avail. I am not sure I understand the meaning of `scanf ("%f", &element) == 1`. Here is what I've learned so far: `while (scanf() != EOF) …` means do something while scanf returns valuable output (until user cooperates and enters correct values). I guess EOF (end of file) is equal to 0. What is a literal meaning  of `scanf() == 1`? Thank you!

Comment: `scanf ("%f%d", &element, &some_int)` returning 1 means that that the #1 field, `"%f"`, successfully put something into it target `element`, but not the #2 field.  If 2 was returned, then both `element` and `some_int` were written.  If 0 was returned, nothing was written into `element` (maybe the first `char` was `'x'`) and nothing into `some_int` and `stdin` is still active.  If `EOF` was returned, it is _some_ negative number and nothing was written into `element` and `some_int` and either `stdin` is now empty (end-of-file) or an input error occurred.

Comment: In general _never_ use `while (scanf() != EOF)`.  It does not mean "means do something while scanf returns valuable output (until user cooperates and enters correct values"  In your case `while (scanf() == 1)` may make sense.  This does mean "returns valuable output" as commented above.

Comment: @chux thank you very much! it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the program to exit directly after this line:

```
printf ("Sorry, invalid input\n");
```

then you must replace the `break` statement directly below that `printf` line with something like this:

```
return 1;
```

On another note, when you want to print error messages, you should use `fprintf()` instead of `printf()`. The entire `for` loop would look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    scanf ("%f", &element);

    is_float = 1;
    n = (int) element;

    if (n - element == 0 || element == 0 )
        {
            is_float = 0;
            fprintf (stderr, "Sorry, invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        } else {
            values[i] = element;
            sum += values[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: @EOF Doesn't `perror` work with `errno` set previously?

Comment: EOF, cad,Anonymous Shadow Thank you! It worked, and thanks to your comments I am a fraction of a step farther in my knowledge :) Thanks!